# Query Update Select not work?

Tags: php, mysql

This query does not work on MySQL with version 5.1 but on the last version of MySQL (5.5) it works.

```
Update furni T1 Set T1.user_id  = (SELECT T2.user_id FROM furni_items T2 where T2.item_id = T1.id) ;
```

How to make query working on MySQL 5.1?

Comment: Are you sure that your subquery returns a result different from what's already in the `user_id` field?

Answer (score 1):

One guess is that the subquery might be returning multiple rows.  You can fix this by using `limit` to get just 1:

```
Update furni T1
    Set T1.user_id  = (SELECT T2.user_id FROM furni_items T2 where T2.item_id = T1.id limit 1)
```

Comment: @user1538524 You say "it does not work". But what exactly is the problem? An error message? It does not update the row as you wish? In order to obtain more accurate answers, maybe you should edit your question to explain *what* the query *should* do and *how* it fails?

Comment: this query not work '0 rows affected'

Answer (score 0):

use join

```
    Update furni T1 
    INNER JOIN furni_items T2
    ON T2.item_id = T1.id
    Set T1.user_id  =  T2.user_id  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess some SQL work differently on correlated updates.  Try this without join syntax, but instead via the where clause.

```
Update furni t1, furni_items t2
   Set t1.user_id = t2.user_id
  Where t1.id = t2.item_id
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @user1538524 , the only thing I can think of is it was case-sensitive T1 vs t1... I was answering from an iPad.  As for the rest of the query, the column names were the same as the column names you had in your original query.